# Django jQuery Ajax form: download a file or render the erroneous form

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-forms

I want a Django-created form to be jQuery/Ajax-submitted; in case of success I want a file to be downloaded, and if the form is not valid I want my Django form to be returned.

I've tried to "highjack" the Django form like that to turn it into a jQuery/Ajax thing:
(javascript code)

```
form.submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      data: form.serialize(), // form data
      type: form.attr('method'),
      url: form.attr('action'),
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          var ctype = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
          if (ctype == 'text/html') {
              $('#div_where_my_form_is').html(data);
          }
          else if (ctype == 'text/csv') {
              // ???? my problem is here
          }
      }
  });
});
```

My Django view code is like this:

```
# (if the form is invalid I return it (simple template containing only the form))
# if valid:
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.csv'
writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=';')
writer.writerow(['...stuff written here...'])
return response
```

So my file is a CSV created on-the-fly, which may be something important to notice.

See how in my jQuery code I use the jqXHR object to check the returned content-type (any better to do this is welcome). My problem is that in case of success, I can't make jQuery understand that this is a file being returned, which should be downloaded. Is that possible? jQuery just treats the data as text.

Possible workarounds:

- make a first ajax call to check the form, and if it's ok make a "normal" (non-ajax) call to download the file
- forget ajax, and in case of invalid form, returned an error page

Answer (score 1):

try [this jquery plugin](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/) it allows for an Ajax-like file download